# Trocar texto ao clicar sobre o mesmo para apresentar/esconder um elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Possuo o seguinte exemplo feito em JavaScript, do qual é um texto escrito "See more", que ao clicar nele ele você é possibilitado de ver mais texto:

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfrS2/2/)

#### Código

```
<head>
  <title>
    Javascript demo - expand/collapse text
  </title>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    // for displaying or hiding parts of the page
    function blocking(nr) {
      displayNew = (document.getElementById(nr).style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
      document.getElementById(nr).style.display = displayNew;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<!-- initially hide the contents of whatItIs and background -->
<body onload="blocking('whatItIs'); blocking('background');">
  <a href="" onclick="blocking('whatItIs'); return false;">See more...</a>
  <br><br>
  <div id="whatItIs">
    Pardus is a GNU/Linux distribution developed in Turkey, as a product of the Pardus Project. It was named after the Anatolian Leopard.
    <br><br>
    Pardus is an easy-to-install and -use operating system, with many enhancements to desktop usability, compatibility and security. With Pardus 1.0 (and the now-released Pardus 2007 version), users can connect to Internet, read e-mails, securely communicate with others and exploit the computer's multimedia capabilities by listening to music and watching movies.
    <br><br>
    Ladislav Bodnar, the creator of DistroWatch, wrote in his round-up of Linux/*nix in 2006 that Pardus is one of the distros he was most impressed by this year "...thanks to unique package management ideas, innovative start-up sequence and general desktop polish..."
    <br><br>
    Pardus is open source and freely distributed as a GPL (General Public License) product. It can be installed in Turkish, English, Spanish, German or Dutch.
    <br><br>
  </div>
</body>
```

Mas tenho uma questão, quando clico em "See more" o texto é mostrado, até aí tudo bem.

## Pergunta

O código que tenho está a funcionar, mas eu gostaria que ao clicar em "See more", o texto mudasse para "Hide" no lugar de "See more". Como atingir este objectivo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes utilizar a função [**`.text()`**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> do JQuery.

Fiz um [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) para veres como funciona, onde no mesmo estou a alterar o texto do elemento HTML com o `id="see"`:

```
if ($("#see").text() == "See more...")
{
    $("#see").text("hide");
}
else {
    $("#see").text("See more...");
}
```

[Exemplo no JSFiddle para uso do `.text()`](http://jsfiddle.net/cesarmiguel/ZfrS2/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Além da opção dada pelo @CesarMiguel, se deseja usar apenas JavaScript, você pode fazer assim:

```
function blocking(nr, click) {
    var elementStyle = document.getElementById(nr).style.display;
    var displayNew = 'none';
    var text = 'See more...';
    if (elementStyle == 'none') {
        displayNew = 'block';
        text = 'Hide text';
    }
    document.getElementById(nr).style.display = displayNew;
    document.getElementById(click).innerHTML = text;
}
```

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsbin.com/jemeyaqo/1/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Para o caso de pretenderes manter o *anonimato* do elemento que recebeu o clique, podes passar o mesmo para dentro da função `blocking`, e a partir dai verificar e atualizar o texto do mesmo em conformidade:

[Exemplo a funcionar no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/355kp/)

#### JavaScript

```
function blocking(nr, e) {

    // trocar texto
    if (typeof e !== 'undefined' && e!='') {
        e.innerHTML = (e.innerHTML=='See more...') ? 'Hide' : 'See more...';
    }

    displayNew = (document.getElementById(nr).style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById(nr).style.display = displayNew;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<a href="" onclick="blocking('whatItIs', this); return false;">See more...</a>
```

---

### Explicação

1. No atributo `onclick`, estamos a passar um segundo parâmetro `this`, que representa o elemento em si.

   ```
   onclick="blocking('whatItIs', this); return false;"
   ```
2. Na função `blocking` recebemos o elemento na variável `e`.

   ```
   function blocking(nr, e)
   ```

   Verificamos se a mesma está definida e não é vazia pois na tag `body` estás a chamar a função para esconder o texto ao inicio.

   ```
   if (typeof e !== 'undefined' && e!='') {
   ```
3. Numa só linha fazemos a actualização do texto, verificando o atual.

   ```
   e.innerHTML = (e.innerHTML=='See more...') ? 'Hide' : 'See more...';
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o `.html()` também caso queria colocar marcadores `HTML`. A deferença entre `.html()` e `.text()` é que o primeiro aceita tags HMLT e XML. Já o segundo vai converter as tags HMLT para textos.

### Exemplo

```
$(this).html('<a href="example.html">Link</a><b>hello</b>')
```

O resultado do script acima seria Exatamente o texto descrito:

```
<a href="example.html">Link</a><b>hello</b>
```

Agora com o outro exemplo

```
$(this).text('<a href="example.html">Link</a><b>hello</b>')
```

Já o resultado do script acima seria

```
&lt;a href="example.html"&gt;Link&lt;/a&gt;&lt;b&gt;hello&lt;/b&gt;
```

Com `escapes`

[Credito da explicação](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html)